# Dependency Injection with database session in router or in repository?

Tags: dependency-injection

I've been wondering for a while how dependency injection with SQL database session should be implemented.

1. **Approach one** - dependency injection with session in the Repository constructor (class with database methods).

**Advantage**:
The advantage of this approach will be that we separate the dependency of routers from repositories, and in this approach the endpoint function does not need to know anything about database sessions.

**Disadvantage**:
If I create an instance of five different repositories in the endpoint function, it will automatically generate five sessions, which may reduce the performance of the application.

2. **Approach two** - injecting dependencies directly in the endpoint function.

**Advantage:**
In this approach, I can generate or issue from the pool one database session for five different repository instances for one request, which seems to me a more efficient solution. In addition, I can decide that, for example, for endpoints where I only fetch data, I can use a shared session generated at application startup which further improves performance.

**Disadvantage:**
The code seems less modular to me and additionally I mix the API with the Database Repositories a bit.

Which approach do you think is more suitable and why?

Code example:

1. **Approach one**

Enpoint function:

```py
@router.get("/user-module/get-current-user/", response_model=UserModel)
async def get_current_user(
    repositories_registry: RepositoriesRegistryABC = Depends(get_repositories_registry),
    token = Depends(http_bearer), 
    ):

    try:
        user_postgres_repository = await repositories_registry.return_user_postgres_repository()
```

Repository:

```py
class UserPostgresRepository:
    __slots__ = 'session'
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)
```

2. **Approach two**

Endpoint function:

```py
@router.get("/user-module/get-current-user/", response_model=UserModel)
async def get_current_user(
    repositories_registry: RepositoriesRegistryABC = Depends(get_repositories_registry),
    token = Depends(http_bearer), 
    postgres_session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)
    ):

    try:
        user_postgres_repository = await repositories_registry.return_user_postgres_repository(postgres_session)
```

Repository:

```py
class UserPostgresRepository:
    __slots__ = 'session'
    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession) -> None:
        self.session: AsyncSession = session
```